# Split "this edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post" into two different bullets

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

The edit review reason stated as "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." is pretty ambiguous.

How are incorrectness and commenting related? It seems to me that it is content against form… Actually, I feel the latter is more related to "This edit changes too much of the original post".

Furthermore, how is the user having suggested the edit supposed to know whether his/her edit is indeed incorrect? It's quite frustrating when you got rejected edits or votes for such a reason, and you're left wondering whether you're wrong or people would just prefer you to comment.

I suggest to split this label into "This edit is incorrect" and "This edit is an attempt to reply or comment on the existing post," and clarify "This edit is incorrect" to be more specific.

Comment: Maybe by 'incorrect' they mean 'incorrect form'? E.g., it's not something that should be done in an edit? Though I do agree that, as stated, the reason is ambiguous and broad.

Comment: "this edit is incorrect" is super vague, I really wouldn't leave that as a stand-alone option

Comment: @Stephan maybe change into "This edit is incorrect, because " `Free Text to input`?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/?cb=1

Answer (score -7):

The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) has this to say about editing (emphasis mine):

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - **To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place**
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

It says that only comments which provide relevant information to the post should be edited in. It also means that comments asking for clarification, spam, socializing and whatnot are not permitted as edits and are therefore *incorrect*.

Comment: But "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post." does not need to be related to comments. It tells: Incorrect OR blabla comments blabla

Comment: I see the second part of the text as an example of the first part. I think this is a problem of english language *or* vs. programming *or*. I don't see this *or* as an XOR.

Comment: Also, this is starting to go off topic but "To include additional information only found in comments" seems to contradict with the common edit rejection reason mentioned in this question : "This edit is […] an attempt to […] comment on the existing post".

Comment: Nor do I, I read this as a logical OR. That means that those two events might be, but could as well not be related. I mean I can imagine a lot of incorrect edits, including edits trying to reply to an existing post. For me the second part of that message represents a subset of the first. "Edit trying to reply or to comment" ⊆ "Incorrect edit"